# What age can I live to?

Tags: lifespans

Are there any Torah sources that imply that a person can not live past the age of 120 ? Have there been verified cases of people living past 120 ?

Comment: http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt25b24.htm#15

Comment: interesting article: http://www.theatlantic.com/science/archive/2016/10/humans-wont-ever-live-far-beyond-115-years/502967/

Comment: I don't understand the question. You live to when Hashem decrees you live to. Your deeds can make that number vary, but that's how long you'll live, whatever that number might be.

Answer (score 1):

The [Ibn Ezra](http://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.6?lang=bi&p2=Ibn_Ezra_on_Genesis.6.3.3&lang2=en) comments on [Breishis 6:3](http://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.6?lang=bi) the following.

(*Source provided by [Sefaria.org](http://www.sefaria.org)*)

> **והיו ימיו**. יש אומרים שזה קצב כל האדם ואם מצאנו יותר כן מצאנו מעט. רק על הרוב ידבר. ואין זה אמת כי הנה שם חיה שש מאות וכל הדורות אחריו חיו שנים רבות ובימי פלג חסרו השנים ומימות דוד עד היום שבעים או שמונים שנה
>
> ***And his days shall be:*** There are those who say that this is the amount of time people have (to live) and if we find (people living longer than that) we will find few. **This is only speaking about the majority of people.** And this isn't true for Shem lived for six hundred years and all the generations afterwards lived many years and in the days of Peleg the years (of man) reduced and in the days of David until today its only 70 or 80 years

That being said it is to be noted that others disagree with this understanding of the pasuk and say it is speaking of the time that H-Shem gave to mankind to repent ( See [Rashi](http://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.6?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Genesis.6.3.4&lang2=bi) and [Sforno](http://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.6.3?lang=bi&with=Sforno&lang2=he)). While others (See [Chizkuni](http://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.6.3?lang=bi&with=Chizkuni,%20Genesis&lang2=he)) agree to this understanding.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

moses died at 120. maybe that's where the idea came from or perhaps it is a misinterpretation of the 120 years warning till the flood of parsha Noach

Comment: Seems that the great sage, Hillel, also lived until 120.

Comment: @DanF i read somewhere he was a gilgul of moshe. this is why he was so humble

Comment: The two 120's parallel each other. See Chullin 139b.